# Applescript does not work on every Mac the same

Tags: networking, applescript, vpn, copying

I have written a short Script, which should copy a file from a network-server on my work (connected my home-network via VPN), but the script is only working on two Macs (of my three), but not on all of them. I have connected all three Macs via ethernet-cable. On the working Macs the script detects the files, but on the third it does not. All firewall-settings are the same and it works on the working Macs via Wifi and Ethernet.

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://10.3.43.1/Backup"
end tell


delay 2.0


property source_Backup : "Backup:"
property destination_Backup : "Macintosh HD:Users:max:Desktop:Testdata:"

try
    with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds
        tell application "Finder"
            set the_file to last item of (sort (get files of folder source_Backup whose name extension is "001") by modification date)
            copy the_file to folder destination_Backup
        end tell
    end timeout
end try
```

At the mounting process it gives me (on all Macs) the Error-code --> error number -10004

Comment: Error -10004 (`errAEPrivilegeError`) is most likely from using the `mount volume` command in a **Finder** tell statement.  Using commands from **StandardAdditions** like that usually get passed up the chain, but the error is logged (probably as a reminder not to do that).

Comment: What model are the three Macs in question? are they all running the same version of the OS?

Comment: The working Macs are a 2017 MacBook Pro with an external Ethernet-Adapter (Wifi works too) and a 2015 iMac 27‘ with internal Ethernet. The Not working model is a 2018 Mac mini an does not work via Wifi, internal Ethernet or external Ethernet. All models are running the same (latest) macOS. I have had the problems  for nearly half a year (when I bougth the Mac mini) and had always installed the latest updates

Comment: Does the 2018 model have a T2 chip? If so, you may be running into a security problem which wouldn't show up on the other two models (even if they have the same OS). I'll have to look into that. That being said, I'm a bit surprised this works at all: `copy` has never been implemented in the Finder, so far as its scripting dictionary says. Try using the `move` or `duplicate` commands instead.